# Clearing Input Fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at this for the last few hours, and can't really achieve what I'm looking for. I currently have the following two inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="USERNAME" onfocus="inputFocused(this)" onblur="inputBlurred(this)" />
<input type="password" id="password" value="PASSWORD" onfocus="inputFocused(this)" onblur="inputBlurred(this)" />
```

Initially, the inputs text is grey, and I have the following JavaScript functions onfocus and onblur:

```
var defaultInput = "";

function inputFocused(obj){
    defaultInput = obj.value;   
    obj.value = "";
    obj.style.color = "#000";
}

function inputBlurred(obj){
    if(obj.value == ""){
        obj.style.color = "#AAA";
        obj.value = defaultInput;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to devise a way so that once I start typing into a field, leave the field, then return, it will not clear the input again (since it will then contain something the user typed in it). I've thought of achieving this with some kind of variable that I can alternate between 1 and 0 depending on the state, but that seemed sloppy. Any insight for this JS novice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **inputFocused**, you are clearing the input field's value regardless of any state. Maybe I am misunderstanding your intention, but why would you ditch the value when focusing the control?

**Updated**: Adding a '**defaultTextValue**' attribute to each element allows you to capture the input's default value on the first focus event. The alternative is to use your document's **onLoad** event to capture the default values. The snippet below clears the textboxes when they are focused and their value is the same as the default values they were initialized with. You might annoy users that have either a username of 'username' or a password of 'password', but you probably should anyways 8-)

```
function inputFocused(obj) {

    if (obj.defaultTextValue == undefined || obj.value == obj.defaultTextValue) {
        obj.defaultTextValue = obj.value;   
        obj.value = "";
    }
}

function inputBlurred(obj) {

    if (obj.value == "" && obj.defaultTextValue != undefined) {
        obj.value = obj.defaultTextValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to ditch the value when focusing only the first time it gets focused. It's default value is USERNAME and the text is grey. On focus, I want to clear the value and change the color to black for user input.

Comment: Updated the code snippet. I think this does what you're looking for.

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware of the ability to add custom attributes, but this looks perfect. I'll have to read on the subject, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to jscharf's code, you can use the title attribute of the input field to store the default value of each input.  This has the usability advantage of letting people know what the input field should contain when they hover over it:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="USERNAME" title="USERNAME" onfocus="inputFocused(this)" onblur="inputBlurred(this)" />
<input type="password" id="password" value="PASSWORD" title="PASSWORD" onfocus="inputFocused(this)" onblur="inputBlurred(this)" />
```

And in the js:

```
function inputFocused(obj){
   if(obj.title != obj.value){
      obj.value = '';
      obj.style.color = '#000';
   }
}

function inputBlurred(obj){
   if(obj.value == '' || obj.title == obj.value){
      obj.value = obj.title;
      obj.style.color = '#AAA';
   }
}
```

Also, not sure if you've considered doing it, but you can control the focus colour of the input in CSS if you want (doesn't work in IE6 of course... but you can override in an IE6 only stylesheet):

```
input {
   color: #AAA;
}


input:focus {
   color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add any customized attributes to your HTML page's DOM as you like, gives you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check to see if the value in the field currently is the initial value.

Comment: That's kind of where my catch-22 is. If I add if(obj.value == defaultInput){...} then I would have to know the elements value before focus, right?